# Class template and constexpr constructor

Tags: c++, constexpr

```
template <typename Wrapped>
class Wrapper
{
public:
    template <typename... Ts>
    constexpr Wrapper(Ts&&... ts)
    : wrapped(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)
    {
    }

private:
    Wrapped wrapped;
};
```

Given such an example, I have a question:

> What standard says about non-constexpr `Wrapped` types?

What if `Wrapper` would not have a `constexpr` constructor?

Comment: From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr): *"For constexpr function templates and constexpr member functions of class templates, at least one specialization must satisfy the abovementioned requirements. Other specializations are still considered as constexpr, even though a call to such a function cannot appear in a constant expression."*

Comment: @Jarod42 Does it mean that if there exists `Wrapped` for which this `constexpr` constructor can be used in constant expression then this constructor is well-formed?

Comment: `constexpr` specifies that the value of a variable or function *can* appear in constant expressions, not *must*.

Comment: @vojana: it should exist at least a `Wrapped` and a `Ts` pack for which it is constexpr.