# Constexpr destructor

Tags: c++, destructor, c++20, constexpr

I've just read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69813886/class-template-and-constexpr-constructor).

Does `constexpr` work in the same manner for destructors? Namely, if the destructor is marked as constexpr, there must exist at least one set of template arguments for which the destructor will be a constant expression? For others the destructor will still compile with `constexpr` keyword even though it will not be a constant expression?

Comment: Have you read [Why can't a destructor be marked constexpr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45071876/why-cant-a-destructor-be-marked-constexpr)?

Comment: Yes, it did not answer my question.

Comment: I've also read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69856905/constexpr-destructor-of-a-class-with-union-field-containing-not-trivial-type) and it proves that compilers behaviour is not consistent.

Comment: What about the notes [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) noting:  "For constexpr function templates and constexpr member functions of class templates, at least one specialization must satisfy the abovementioned requirements"